# Training error in linear regression can always be made zero, given certain condition?

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning, regression

I was going through the derivation of linear regression and wanted to verify that what I understood is indeed correct?

We minimize this
$$  {\lVert y -Xw  \rVert}^2 $$

where y is a $n*1$ dimensional vector , X is our data which is  $n * d$, and w is a $d*1$ dimensional vector.

**Note: Both y and X belong to the training set, as in we are learning $ w_{ls} = {(X^TX)}^{-1} X^Ty $**

Now we can reach every possible y, by some linear combination of columns of X, if there are at least n linearly independent columns in $X$.

So we would always be able to find a weight vector w, that makes the total error zero when the above condition hold (**is this a right deduction?**)

In Matrix Representation, consider we have 4 data points

$
 \implies
  \begin{bmatrix}
    y1 \\
    y2 \\
    y3 \\
    y4 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x11 & x12 & x13 & x14 \\
    x21 & x22 & x23 & x24 \\
    x31 & x32 & x33 & x34  \\
    x41 & x42 & x43 & x44 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    w1 \\
    w2 \\
    w3  \\
    w4 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$

we see that Y is a vector in $R^n$, as X has $n$ linearly independent columns, we can represent every point in $R^n$ as a combination of the columns of X  For eg.

$
 \implies
  \begin{bmatrix}
    y1 \\
    y2 \\
    y3 \\
    y4 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x11  \\
    x21 \\
    x31   \\
    x41  \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    w1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
+
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x12  \\
    x22 \\
    x32   \\
    x42  \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    w2 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
+
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x13  \\
    x23 \\
    x33   \\
    x43  \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    w3 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
+
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x14  \\
    x24 \\
    x34   \\
    x44  \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    w4 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$

Now our training labels with n datapoints points can be represented as a single vector in $R^n$ dimensional space, And any values of ${[y1,y2,y3,y4]}^T$ represent a point in this space.

Since all points are reachable by a linear combination of columns, any values of ${[y1,y2,y3,y4]}^T$ must also be reachable and hence error should be zero.

This essentially boils down to, that we can always make the training error zero for a particular ${[y1,y2,y3,y4]}^T$ value, by selecting the right weights.

Answer (score 1):

> Now we can reach every possible y, by some linear combination of columns of X, if there are at least n linearly independent columns in . So we would always be able to find a weight vector w, that makes the total error zero when the above condition hold (is this a right deduction?)

This is only true if we know that the entries of $y$ will exactly be a linear function of the rows of $X$ (consider the case where there is some noise, in which case you wont be able to exactly drive the error to $0$).

> Now when X does not have n linearly independent columns, we can only reach some lower dimension then the dimensions in which y exists , and there would be a non zero error term? (is this true?)

I'm not sure what you mean by "reach some lower dimension".

You need to specify some assumptions on how $y, X$ are related. For example, assume that:

$$y_i = x_i^Tw + \epsilon$$

where $\epsilon \sim N(0, 1)$ is additive gaussian noise. In this case, given $n>d$ samples, we can minimize the squared error by using the formula for $w$ that you've given above.

In contrast to solving a consistent system of equations such as $\alpha = A\beta$ for $beta$ where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, usually when solving for a least square solution, our $X$ is not full-rank (not invertible), so we cannot simply compute $w = X^{-1}y$. Instead, the formula you've given computes $w$ such that $Aw$ is the orthogonal projection of $y$ onto the range of $X$. This what you want since the orthogonal projection onto the range of $X$ is exactly: $\min \|y-u\|_2^2$ subject to $u = Xw$.

Comment: "This is only true if we know that the entries of y will exactly be a linear function of the rows of X (consider the case where there is some noise, in which case you wont be able to exactly drive the error to 0)."  

If we have n independent columns, we can consider them to be the basis for some new system, since the basis can be used to express all possible points with a linear combination, we can reach all values of y , then shouldn't it be true?

Comment: I think that there's some confusion here between two similar-sounding things: the error *in approximating the given points*, and the error *in predicting future points*. The second kind of error can't be driven to 0 if there's noise, no matter how high the dimension is...

Comment: Yes, though what i mean is reducing the error for the given points for which we know both x and y, not the future points, I am just asking if its always possible to reduce the error on the training set to be zero, given the conditions above?

I have also edited the question to make it clear!

Comment: The statement youre making about the columns spanning the space means that a single point can be expressed as a linear combination of the rows. But if i have multiple points and, for example, there is noise, then each one will require a different $w$ to perfectly express $y$

Comment: @MONODA43 I have added further clarification.

Comment: To answer your updated question: yes, if you have $n$ samples in $n$ dimensions and the columns are linearly independent, then you can find a solution that makes the training error 0. But of course you would be overfitting unless you know the relationship is exactly linear. After all, you've just described solving a system of equations.